# Hide div when user clicks outside unless closing lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using the following code to allow a user to show/hide a div on click.
When clicking anywhere outside of the div, it closes the div.

However, there is a link within the div which can open a lightbox. When a user goes to close that lightbox, it also closes the div that the link was contained. Is there anything I can add into the script to stop that from happening?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("a.dropdown-link").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var $div = $(this).next('.info-container');
  $(".info-container").not($div).slideUp();
    if ($div.is(":visible")) {
        $div.slideUp()
    }  else {
       $div.slideDown();
    }
});

$(document).click(function(e){
    var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length
    if (!p) {
          $(".info-container").slideUp();
    }
});
     $('.movie-link').magnificPopup({type:'iframe'});
});

<a class="dropdown-link" href="#"><div class="dropdown dropdown-processed">More info</div></a>
<div class="info-container" style="display: none;">Video preview: <a class="movie-link" href="videourl"></a></div>
```

I'm using Magnific Popup for the lightbox: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

My JavaScript knowledge is pretty basic so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "click to close div function, you can check if the lightbox is on or not. A simple `if ($("#lightbox").css("display") == "none")` should be able to do the trick

EDIT: put this line after the `$(document).ready` line

```
var state = 0; // default state
$('.movie-link').click(function() { state = 1; }); // state = 1, lightbox on
```

in the source code, on line 384, insert this code

```
state = 2; //state = 2, lightbox close button clicked
```

the idea is not firing the "close div" function when the state is 1 (lightbox is on and clicking random stuffs inside, or outside the lightbox) or 2 (lightbox's close button got clicked), and return state to 0 when it was 2

so instead of the `if` I provided in the comment use this

```
if (state == 2) {
    state = 0;
} else if (state == 0) {
    //rest of the code
}
```

this is just something I put together and haven't tested yet, so I don't actually know if it works or not so just back up your js files just in case.

EDIT 2:

remove all the changes in edit 1 and use this on instead of the `if (state == 2) {`

```
if (e.target != $('.mfp-bg')[0] and e.target != $('.mfp-wrap')[0]) {
```

EDIT 3

```
var e_class = $(e.target).attr('class');
if (e_class != 'mfp-close' && e_class != 'mfp-container') {
```

working example: http://imgcrash.comeze.com/test.html

Comment: Thanks for the code, I'm sorry i'm not entirely sure where this should go. Do I just need to put this before the `var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length` ?

Comment: @jacobgibbs yes, you will need to cover the whole code with {} but i think you know that already.

Comment: Could you take a look at the lightbox example I'm using? The link is http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/. Specifically the youtube iframe example, it doesn't seem to utilise display:none. Is there any alternative check I can make?

Comment: @jacobgibbs just wondering but did you change the `#lightbox` to the correct id / class that is the lightbox? I just checked through the example provided on the site and it was `.mfp-wrap`, but it might be different on your side

Comment: I did, I haven't changed the popup code so it's still `.mfp-wrap`. Using the following code it allows me to close the lightbox without hiding the info-container div, but then when I click anywhere outside the div it won't close. `$(document).click(function(e){
if ($(".mfp-wrap").css("display") == "none"){
    var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length
    if (!p) {
          $(".info-container").slideUp();
    }
    }
});`

Comment: @jacobgibbs use `if($("#.mfp-wrap").length == 0) {` then. It seems instead of setting `display:none` it actually removed the whole lightbox

Comment: This causes the div to close as you close the lightbox, presumably because the length of `.mfp-wrap` becomes 0 again. Is there any way around this? All other functionality works again though.

Comment: @jacobgibbs do you have access to the source code of the lightbox? Alternatively you can write your own lightbox plugin though

Comment: Source files are here: [CSS](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/blob/master/dist/magnific-popup.css) and [JS](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/blob/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js). I am hosting them on my own site too, so I can modify them. I really appreciate all your help

Comment: @jacobgibbs I've edited the answer, see if it works and tell me

Comment: `state = 2;` seems to break the lightbox, it just reverts to loading the YouTube page now. I get the thinking of making a new state for when the lightbox is closed so there is a new state to check against.

Comment: The new if statement in EDIT 2 stops the div from opening in the first place. I'm assuming that it's blocking it because it can see the lightbox is off so the click to close is overriding the click to open?

Comment: @jacobgibbs can you give me your website? I might find out what went wrong. Again, it would be better if you can use a more basic self-coded lightbox. If you want to I can write a simple lightbox that display youtube video for you.

Comment: Here's a test page: http://outyet.s3.amazonaws.com/test.html I've reverted back to my original javascript code so you can start from scratch. I have no idea how to write a lightbox, I chose this one because it seemed to work well with responsive websites?

Comment: @jacobgibbs use this `var e_class = $(e.target).attr('class'); if (e_class.indexOf('mfp-close') != -1 && e_class.indexOf('mfp-wrap') != -1) {`, I got it worked on my test page: http://imgcrash.comeze.com/test.html

Comment: In your test page I don't seem to be able to close the div by clicking anywhere outside it like on my example?

Comment: @jacobgibbs I changed the `if` statement to `if (e_class != 'mfp-close' && e_class != 'mfp-container') {` and it seems to work, check if I missed anything

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! I wish I had enough reputation to upvote as well. Really appreciated.

Comment: Hoping you could help again... I've updated the page here: http://outyet.s3.amazonaws.com/test.html to include an 'email reminder' link that loads a form in a lightbox (ignore the styling). However, when you click on the form container (or inside any of the form fields) it closes the div again. The form still loads mfp-container & mfp-close so I thought it would work the same as the youtube lightbox, but it doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% without actually testing this out but you may be running into issues with `$(document).click(...);` since clicking anywhere on the `document` would trigger this event.

When you close the popup you're probably triggering this event and sliding up the `info-container` div.

It seems that you're looking for clicks on the divs with the class `.dropdown`. Why not use something like:

`$('.dropdown').click(function(e) { ... });`

Comment: I changed both references of `$(document)` to `$('.dropdown')` and it now allows you to close the lightbox without the info-container div closing, however the div doesn't close when the user clicks anywhere outside of it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a.dropdown-link").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation(); //We stop the propagation of the event

  //Changed it to slideToggle and added stop to prevent weird animation
    //on multiple clicks
  $(this).next('.info-container').stop().slideToggle()
});

$(document).click(function(e){
    //Check if it has the class info-container
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass("info-container")) {
          $(".info-container").slideUp();
    }
});
     $('.movie-link').magnificPopup({type:'iframe'});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SmV8m/)

Comment: Hmm i see the same behavior in the jsfiddle with or without the `evt.stopPropagation` , am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the code. This seems to be causing the div to slide up as the lightbox opens, despite the lightbox link being within the info-container div.

Comment: If you delete the evt.stopPropagation() the click event added to the document will receive the click event also, and because the element has not the info-container class it will close the container after the slideDown, that's the difference, with the stopPropagation if you click the link the container will receive the slideDown animation and if you click inside of it, it will remain open until you click something outside

Comment: If you add some text between the link tags, you can see how when the link is clicked the div slides up again. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmV8m/2/)

Comment: That example still seems to close the div when you click the close button on the lightbox?